# Is it possible to write a SQL query to return specific rows, but then join some columns of those rows with another table?

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to write this query.

A hypothetical problem that is that same as the one I'm trying to solve:

Say I have a table of `apples`. Each `apple` has numerous attributes, such as `color_id`, `variety_id` and the `orchard_id` they were picked from.

The `color_id`, `variety_id`, and `orchard_id` all refer to their respective tables: `colors`, `varieties`, and `orchards`.

Now, say I need to query for all `apples` that have `color_id = '3'`, which refers to `yellow` in the `colors` table.

I want to somehow obtain this `yellow` value from the query.

Make sense?

Here's what I was trying:

`SELECT * FROM apples, colors.id WHERE color_id = '3'`
`LEFT JOIN colors ON apples.color_id = colors.id`

Comment: Luckily, the people who designed sql managed to get it to cover this hypothetical situation : )

Comment: Lucky for me, you can't select the apple sitting on my desk, since it is red :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do the join in general. It will return all apples whether or not a color is specified:

```
SELECT * 
FROM apples a
LEFT OUTER JOIN colors c ON a.color_id = c.id
```

If you only want yellow apples, it should probably be an inner join, since you are requiring that a.color_id not be null in your where clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM apples a
INNER JOIN colors c ON a.color_id = c.id
WHERE a.color_id = 3
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT *  
FROM apples a 
INNER JOIN colors c ON a.color_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN orchards o ON a.orchard_id = o.id 
WHERE a.color_id = 3 and a.orchard_id = 5
```

Comment: to do multiple conditions you combine them all under one WHERE clause at the end, combining conditions with AND.

INNER JOIN .... ON .... INNER JOIN .... ON .... WHERE .... AND ....

Answer (score 1):

Use this sql query:

```
SELECT apples.*, color.name
FROM apples
JOIN colors ON apples.color_id = colors.id
WHERE colors.id = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*, c.ColorName
FROM Apples a INNER JOIN Colors c ON a.color_id = c.color_id
WHERE c.color_id = 3
```